# Typescript: How to use drawHeaderRow to create table with horizontal headers?

Tags: json, typescript, angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

jsPDF allows to create a table form JSON data and save that table into a PDF document. I have created a Angualr2/Typescript [application](http://embed.plnkr.co/CX94bBnz8nwCOmdVcZlP/) to do the same. This create table form my JSON data. I'm trying to use jsPDF is create a table with horizontal headers. Example for this given [here](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#horizontal). Code to create that is as follows.

```
// Horizontal - shows how tables can be drawn with horizontal headers
examples.horizontal = function () {
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
  doc.autoTable(getColumns().splice(1,4), getData(), {
    drawHeaderRow: function() {
        // Don't draw header row
        return false;
    },
    columnStyles: {
        first_name: {fillColor: [41, 128, 185], textColor: 255, fontStyle: 'bold'}
    }
  });
  return doc;
};
```

Complete code is available [here](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js). This code is written in JavaScript. I'm looking for a way to convert this into Typescript. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: It should already be valid typescript if it works in javascript? The autotable plugin does not have any typings so your code might be the best way to go. Any reason you want to write it in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component might look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
    `<h1>JSON to PDF app</h1>
    <div class="container" id="div1">
        <button id="create" (click)="convert('base')">Create file</button> 
        <button id="create" (click)="convert('horizontal')">
           Create file with horizontal table
        </button> 
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  cols: Array<any> = [{
      title: "Details",
      dataKey: 'details'
    }, {
      title: "Values",
      dataKey: 'values'
   }];

  optionsContainer = {
    base: {},
    horizontal: {
      drawHeaderRow: () => false,
      columnStyles: {
          details: {fillColor: [41, 128, 185], textColor: 255, fontStyle: 'bold'}
      }
    }
  };

  rows: Array<any> = [];

  constructor() {
    const item = {
      "Name" : "XYZ",
      "Age" : "22",
      "Gender" : "Male"
    }; 

    this.rows = Object.keys(item).map((key) => {  
      return { 'details': key, 'values': item[key] };
    });
  }

  convert(action){
    const doc = new jsPDF()
       .autoTable(this.cols, this.rows, this.optionsContainer[action]);
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
  }
}
```

**[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5yYBBfv45Um78Md7EMv3?p=preview)**

Comment: The new table header column 'details' was missing the style. Just had to put it inside ''.

Comment: I've changed a bit my answer

Comment: Thank you. This answer saved my day.